# SSL protocols not supported in Standalone Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I downloaded the core binary distribution of tomcat 7 at https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

I extracted the content of the archive as a directory called tomcat. This tomcat binaries can run directly as long as I provide the environment variables. So I use a script to set JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME and then I start the server using the default script:

tomcat/bin/startup.sh

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   ./tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   ./tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: ./tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       ./tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:./tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
...
...
Jul 15, 2015 3:34:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getEnableableProtocols
WARNING: None of the SSL protocols specified are supported by the SSL engine : [TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2]
```

In my server.xml I have

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="..." keystorePass="..."
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2" 
               address="0.0.0.0"/>
```

I can't manage to fix this "not supported protocols" when running the server. I think it comes from the loading of the jsse library that provides these protocols, but I have the jar available under /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar and I also tried to copy it to tomcat/lib/ to make sure it would end up on the classpath, and it didn't work.

What is going wrong with these protocols and how could I get them to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are space- or comma-separated, not '+'-separated. Check the documentation. You're using the OpenSSL syntax and a non-OpenSSL connector.